What's the correlation of $\max(X,0)$ and $\min(0, X)$ when $X$ follows normal distribution?
We know $\max(X,0)$ is $X$ and $\min(X, 0)$ is $0$ when $X>0$, and $\max(X,0)$ is $0$ and $\min(X, 0)$ is $X$ when $X<0$.
Let $Z=\max(X, 0)$ and $Y=\min(X, 0)$, intuitively we have $$E(ZY)=0, \qquad E(Z)E(Y)<0, \qquad
E(Z+Y)=E(X)=0$$ and
$$\operatorname{corr}(Z,Y)=\frac{\operatorname{cov}(Z,Y)}{\operatorname{std}(Z)\operatorname{std}(Y)}=\frac{-E(Z)E(Y)}{\operatorname{std}(Z)\operatorname{std}(Y)}>0.$$
Edits:
$$\begin{align}
E(Z)&=\int_{0}^{\infty}x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\tfrac{x^2}{2}}\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\tfrac{u}{2}}\mathrm du
\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[-2e^{-\tfrac{u}{2}}\right]^{\infty}_{0}
\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}.
\end{align}
$$
$$E(Y)=-E(Z)$$
$$E(Y^{2}+Z^{2})=E(Y^{2})+E(Z^{2})=E(X^2)=1
\\E(Y^{2})=E(Z^{2})=\frac{1}{2}
\\ \operatorname{Var}(Y)=\operatorname{Var}(Z)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi}.
$$
So,
$$\operatorname{corr}(Z, Y)=\frac{\frac{1}{2\pi}}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2\pi}}=\frac{1}{\pi-1}.$$

Seems like a number that should be explicitly computable.

Hint: use the PDF of the standard normal distribution to show
$$
\mathbb E\min(X,0)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}=-\mathbb E\max(X,0),,\quad
\mathbb E[\min(X,0)^2]=\mathbb E[\max(X,0)^2]=\frac12,.
$$
This gives a correlation of
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi(\frac12-\frac1{2\pi})}=\frac 1{\pi-1}\approx 0.467.
$$

Thanks for the comments. Edited the answer to the problem directly.
